# Why do I need to use M when declaring a decimal

Tags: c#

When I try to declare a variable like this:

```
decimal order = 5.0;
```

I get the error message "Literal of type double cannot be implicitly converted to type 'decimal'; use an 'M' suffix to create a liter of this type."

Can someone explain why the M is needed?

Comment: Because `5.0` is a double and not a decimal. And a conversion from `double` to `decimal` isn't automatic and can't be because their ranges are not the same.

Comment: You should probably just use double to not have to worry about the M

Comment: @FirebladeDan Bad idea - double and float are horrible choices for variables that represent actual decimal amounts (money, percentages, etc.)  they are good for naturally imprecise measurements (temperature, height, etc.)

Comment: You *can* use `decimal order = 5;` because of the implicit conversion from integer types to `decimal`. But that will become `5M` (after the invisible conversion) which is not quite the same as `5.0M`.

Comment: @DStanley - I think you exaggerated that quite a bit. Double will work just fine for his order 5.0 with ONE SIGNIFICANT DIGIT. I doubt he'll need the 20+ digits unless he's building a robot to do spinal surgery...

Comment: @FireBladeDan It's not about the precision, it's about accurate binary representation. `(0.15 + 0.15 == 0.10 + 0.20)` will return `false`.  Good luck explaining that to your accounting manager.

Comment: @FirebladeDan Status: Currently Seeking Employment. (Learned something *thanks @DStanley)

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN:decimal C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the
>   suffix m or M, for example:
>
> `decimal myMoney = 300.5m;`
>
> Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double and generates
>   a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Any numeric literal with a decimal point but no suffix is of type `double`. From the C# 5 specification, section 2.4.4.3:

> If no *real-type-suffix* is specified, the type of the real literal is `double`. Otherwise, the real type suffix determines the type of the real literal, as follows: [...]

There's no implicit conversion from `double` to `decimal`, so trying to assign a `double` value to a `decimal` variable fails.

You'd get the same thing if you wanted a `float` value:

```
float x = 5.0; // Nope, same problem
```

You *could* explicitly cast to `float` or `decimal`, but that would be a bad idea for `float` and a *very* bad idea for `decimal`.